# Joining two tables?

Tags: geocoding, attribute-joins

I have two tables, a Census tract table with population numbers and a table with student information (but no addresses).

I need to combine the tables to make graduated color maps, such as the average GPA per tract and many more.

The only field that I can see using in the Census tracts table (the only field with distinct values per row other than the Object ID, length and area fields) is the GEO_ID field of tract numbers (there are multiple sets of tracts with the same numbers).

However, this is not in the student info table (neither are the others).  We received the student data already geocoded (so we wouldn't have to see the addresses for privacy rights).

When I did a spatial join of the student table to the Census tract table, it gave me a Count per tract field (of course), but removed all of the student data.

I did a Reverse geocode, but the values I got were not the same as the GEO_ID values in the other table (The Address Locator I used was the default MGRS).

I have linked the two attribute tables as .xls files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/em696y77h8c601m/EnrollmentTracts.xls?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yz2e4j532zrq5rz/FallStudents2015_Projected_Clipped.xls?dl=0

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? What were the precise tools and parameter values that you used on a step where what you observed was not what you expected?

Comment: Hello PolyGeo,  I think your question kicked my memory into gear.  Believe I just had to switch around my spatial join.  Please let me make sure I've got it in order, though, before you close my question. I'll respond again tomorrow evening either way.  Thanks a lot for the jostle.

Comment: .     So, today I did a join in the Table of Contents on the student data table, using "join data from another layer based on spatial location," "it falls inside," and the original census tracts table as the one to join to the student data (this is the opposite of what I had done before).  This gave me the GEO_ID in the same table with the student data.

Comment: I then used the spatial join tool from arctoolbox, using my newly created table as the Target Features and the EnrollmentTracts table as the Join Features in a One-To-One join.  This resulted in the following table: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/8189d07r2ub7q2t/Fall2015_Students_toCensus2_toEnrollmentTracts.xls?dl=0>  Now I need to somehow combine the credit hours by unique GEO_ID to make a graduated color map.  Would using a python script work best?  I'm not too familiar with the language yet.  Thanks again, Andrew

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with those details.  Many potential answerers only have time to read the questions and not the comments on them so it is the question body that needs to have any important information.  Please be aware that many potential answerers (including me) will never follow links to get data so the data should instead be described within the question body.

Comment: @Andrews please edit your question to include the methods of how you are joining the data and the results.  We need to be able to duplicate your problem to give you an answer.

Comment: This question should be closed now, thank you for your help.